# Installing Aggregate Polygons Function in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I've been trying to run a sql function written by Dr. Horst Duester, found in http://www.kappasys.ch/cms/index.php?id=65&L=5, which is used to aggregate detached polygons. It requires that two functions be installed first:

```
$ psql <dbname> -U <user> -h <server> -f cleanGeometry.sql

$ psql <dbname> -U <user> -h <server> -f aggregatePolygons.sql
```

both of which can be downloaded from the aforementioned web page.

I have managed to install the first, but when I try the second I get the following error message in the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>psql -d test_db_1 -U postgres -h localhost -
f aggregatePolygons.sql

Password for user postgres:

psql:aggregatePolygons.sql:56: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ο?Ώ"
LINE 1: ο?Ώ      ^

CREATE FUNCTION

psql:aggregatePolygons.sql:89: ERROR:  function _aggregatepolygonsfunction(geome
try, geometry, double precision, boolean) does not exist

GRANT

psql:aggregatePolygons.sql:93: ERROR:  aggregate aggregatepolygons(geometry, dou
ble precision, boolean) does not exist
psql:aggregatePolygons.sql:100: ERROR:  function _aggregatepolygonsfunction(geom
etry, geometry, double precision, boolean) does not exist
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

change line 92:

```
DROP AGGREGATE aggregatepolygons(geometry, double precision, boolean);
```

to this:

```
DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS aggregatepolygons(geometry, double precision, boolean);
```